# cant get virtual host to work in wamp

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, virtualhost

**Version**:2.5
 
I know there are many guides to do this but it does not work for some reason and I can't even this is what I did

**in Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
   ServerName localhost
   <Directory "D:/wamp/www">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/elgg"
   ServerName elgg.local
   ServerAlias elgg.local
   <Directory  "C:/elgg">
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted             
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**in Hosts File**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       elgg.local
::1             elgg.local
```

**in Conf File**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I did all this but when i type elgg.local it searches for an actual website

**last 10 apache lines**

```
[Fri Oct 16 10:33:49.873625 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1576:tid 668]        AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1252
[Fri Oct 16 10:33:50.405080 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1252:tid 600] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:50.487027 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1576:tid 668] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:52.490354 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1252:tid 600] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:52.606432 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1576:tid 668] AH00430: Parent: Child process 1252 exited successfully.
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:54.598384 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6408:tid 656] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:54.598384 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6408:tid 656] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:54.598384 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6408:tid 656] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:54.600385 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6408:tid 656] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8152
[Fri Oct 16 12:09:54.943610 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8152:tid 580] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache after these changes? Did you restart `dnscache` after the Host file chnages. A reboot should do both, does it work after a reboot?

Comment: You also forgot `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` in the `elgg` VHOST config

Comment: @RiggsFolly still does not work

Comment: So what is the error message? look in the apache erro log

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is the last line

Comment: @RiggsFolly [Fri Oct 16 12:09:54.943610 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8152:tid 580] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: @RiggsFolly we can continue here [chat room](http://www.e-chat.co/room/97101)

Comment: That line is the last line of a GOOD Apache startup. Check which service has not started! Maybe its MYSQL now

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope its working

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u come to [chatroom](http://www.e-chat.co/room/97101)

Comment: @RiggsFolly added stuff to the question

Comment: That looks like a perfectly good Apache startup. What makes you think Apache is not running

Comment: @RiggsFolly idid not say apache is not running i said icant get virtual host to work

Comment: So what does not work then. What happens when you enter `elgg.local` in the browser address bar

Comment: @RiggsFolly it searches online just like when you type google what happens the search engine searches for something called google

Comment: Have you rebooted recently or refreshed the DNSCache `net stop dnscache` then `net start dnscache` from command line using "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @RiggsFolly idid it did not work earlier or now

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was not much, if anything, wrong with the Apache config.

However @Tryhard was using the Google Chrome browser, and that was doing a google search whenever the URL `elgg.local` was entered and not using it as a domainname. IE did not make this mistake, so it must be a Chrome issue!

The popular solution, that I have used before, of

*Enter chrome://flags in the address bar and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser.* No longer seems to work as that option is no longer available in the flags parameters.

Dont know if this is a Chrome bug or just an oddity, but the only solution we could come up with was to add a trailing `/` to the domain name. That made Chrome use the url rather than start a search!

So `elgg.local` did a search

and `elgg.local/` ran the website code.

*If you ever get odd unexpected behaviours while using Chrome, always try FF and/or IE before anything else, to make sure the same things happen as Chrome seems to have quite a few odd behaviours when dealing with local development websites.*